# Derby is unable to find en_US properties

Tags: java, derby

I am trying to enable derby for my application and configure it's startup and shutdown from within my application. However I keep getting annoying Exception. Stack Trace is given below -

```
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle org.apache.derby.loc.drda.messages, key en
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.iapi.tools.i18n.LocalizedResource.setResource(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.iapi.tools.i18n.LocalizedResource.getTextMessage(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.iapi.tools.i18n.LocalizedResource.getTextMessage(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.localizeMessage(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.consolePropertyMessageWork(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.consolePropertyMessage(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.setUpSocket(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.impl.drda.NetworkServerControlImpl.shutdown(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl.shutdown(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.delta.dcc.dpl.listener.StartupListener.contextDestroyed(StartupListener.java:26)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextDestroyed(WebApp.java:1675)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.destroy(WebApp.java:2898)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.destroy(WebAppImpl.java:775)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.container.AbstractContainer.destroy(AbstractContainer.java:74)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.destroy(WebGroup.java:201)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.removeWebApplication(WebGroup.java:239)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHost.removeWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:286)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.removeWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:208)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.removeWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:793)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.uninstall(WebContainerImpl.java:408)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.stop(WebContainerImpl.java:679)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stop(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1185)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStop(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1318)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.stop(DeployedModuleImpl.java:646)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.stop(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1092)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:967)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.access$400(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:196)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$2.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1416)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4189)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4367)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplicationImpl(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1422)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stop(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2131)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.stop(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:494)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.stop(CompositionUnitImpl.java:140)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.stopCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:766)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.stopCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:712)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.stopApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1391)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:45)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:36)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:243)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1313)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1206)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:286)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:502)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)
[4/13/16 17:57:23:051 IST] 00000014 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)
```

I have included 4 jars provided by my WAS installation -

```
derby.jar
derbyclient.jar
derbynet.jar
derbytools.jar
```

DERBY Version - 10.3

All I tried so far to start the NetworkServerControl from which is successful but shutting it down gives me this exception trace. I can see a bunch of localization specific jars in my WAS bundle but it does not include the en_US one, seemingly causing this problem.

```
NetworkServerControl server = null;
server = new NetworkServerControl();
server.start(null);
server = new NetworkServerControl();
server.shutdown();
```

I cannot see the property file in question `org.apache.derby.loc.drda.messages` in any of these 4 jars and i don't see any other derby jar included with my WAS package. Can anyone help me with what i should do or where to look for the en_US jar so that I can get rid of this annoying exception?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: 10.3? That's a very old version of Derby. Is it possible that there is another  version of Derby that is being included elsewhere in your classpath which is confusing things? For examples, many versions of Java 7 and Java 8 come with a copy of Derby automatically included, and that copy is much more recent than 10.3.

Comment: Yes, it is true that this version is very old but this is what IBM WAS 7 offers with its packaging and there are no other derby JARS that we are including in our application's classpath apart from the ones offered by WAS or any other version on server. Even the Java is IBM Java 6 so as far as i know it should not be having any Derby jars with that.

Comment: `jar tf derbynet.jar` shows `org/apache/derby/loc/drda/messages.properties` on my system. I continue to suspect a CLASSPATH issue of some sort. The Derby jars are sealed, so any juxtaposition of jars from differing versions produces subtle class-loading failures.

Comment: Sorry for replying back so late. It seems there was a conflict with jars which got resolved after i recreated the projrct in a new workspace. Thanks for your help in this regard